# Angular 5 loading locale with webpack

Tags: angular

Angular 5 provides a way to load i18n locale at runtime using registerLocaleData

https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes

- Add import and register to localdata.

  `import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

  import localeEnIn from '@angular/common/locales/en-IN.js';

  registerLocaleData(localeEnIn);`
- Provider to provide local id

  `providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-IN' } ]`
- **Problem**:
  Can't change the any format to provide in local id
- How to register local data in webpack.

Comment: are you looking to register the `locale` at run time?

Comment: above code try but not change any format. first of all I try to set single local data then I try dynamic load local data. plz help

Comment: the above code should definitely work. can you reproduce the issue using a working example as `plunker` or `stackblitz`?

Comment: Code definitely work on angular-cli but webpack (visual studio 2017) not work. Above code not get error.

Comment: See this example, [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjk6xc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)  Currency can't change..